# html tidy and rails apps - erb or rthml files. Ruby alternative?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, htmltidy

I just installed HTML Tidy plugin for eclipse. I added the html.erb file type and now it will do its magic on my erb files. However it puts in the title tag and changes a lot of my characters to escape characters. How can I stop this from happening - or is there a ruby alternative which will go through my code, reindent, and stick in missing tags? I'm worried about a lot of my erb files since the built in formatter with Aptana is hard to use. I don't see any glaring errors when I view the page, but I'm sure there are some mismatched tags and stuff that I'd like to get rid of. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but found [Rack::Tidy](http://coderack.org/users/webficient/entries/38-racktidy)